# Parsing csv file using smooks returns error null or empty arg

Tags: java, csv, smooks, wso2-esb

i try to parse csv file using latest release of smooks(1.5.1) and wso2 esb ang get error:
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: null or empty 'fields' arg in method call.

My csv file has Multi Record Field Definitions:
Input .csv file(delimeted with tab):

```
T11 T12 T13 T14 T15 T16
T21 T22 T23 T24 T25 T26
T3
```

Proxy Service(only part with smooks config:

```
<smooks config-key="smooks-config">
<input type="text"/>
<output type="xml"/>
</smooks>
```

Smooks configuration file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<localEntry key="smooks-config" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
  <smooks-resource-list xmlns="http://www.milyn.org/xsd/smooks-1.1.xsd" xmlns:csv="http://www.milyn.org/xsd/smooks/csv-1.5.xsd">
    <csv:reader fields="T11[*] | T22[*] | T3[*]" indent="true"
      recordElementName="message" rootElementName="messages" separator="&#x9;"/>
  </smooks-resource-list>
</localEntry>
```

And in result i get exception:

```
TID: [-1234]  [ESB]  [2016-07-07 15:33:16,742] DEBUG -  Start : Smooks mediator {org.wso2.carbon.mediator.transform.SmooksMediator}
TID: [-1234]  [ESB]  [2016-07-07 15:33:16,756] ERROR -  Failed to filter source. {org.wso2.carbon.mediator.transform.SmooksMediator}
org.milyn.SmooksException: Failed to filter source.
    at org.milyn.delivery.sax.SmooksSAXFilter.doFilter(SmooksSAXFilter.java:97)
    at org.milyn.delivery.sax.SmooksSAXFilter.doFilter(SmooksSAXFilter.java:64)
    at org.milyn.Smooks._filter(Smooks.java:526)
    at org.milyn.Smooks.filterSource(Smooks.java:482)
    at org.wso2.carbon.mediator.transform.SmooksMediator.mediate(SmooksMediator.java:131)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:81)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:48)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator.mediate(SequenceMediator.java:149)
    at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.ProxyServiceMessageReceiver.receive(ProxyServiceMessageReceiver.java:185)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:180)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.AbstractTransportListener.handleIncomingMessage(AbstractTransportListener.java:328)
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.vfs.VFSTransportListener.processFile(VFSTransportListener.java:751)
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.vfs.VFSTransportListener.scanFileOrDirectory(VFSTransportListener.java:407)
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.vfs.VFSTransportListener.poll(VFSTransportListener.java:177)
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.vfs.VFSTransportListener.poll(VFSTransportListener.java:124)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.AbstractPollingTransportListener$1$1.run(AbstractPollingTransportListener.java:67)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool$1.run(NativeWorkerPool.java:172)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: null or empty 'fields' arg in method call.
    at org.milyn.assertion.AssertArgument.isNotNullAndNotEmpty(AssertArgument.java:105)
    at org.milyn.flatfile.Record.<init>(Record.java:43)
    at org.milyn.flatfile.variablefield.VariableFieldRecordParser.nextRecord(VariableFieldRecordParser.java:201)
    at org.milyn.flatfile.FlatFileReader.parse(FlatFileReader.java:176)
    at org.milyn.delivery.sax.SAXParser.parse(SAXParser.java:76)
    at org.milyn.delivery.sax.SmooksSAXFilter.doFilter(SmooksSAXFilter.java:86)
    ... 19 more
TID: [-1234]  [ESB]  [2016-07-07 15:33:16,763] ERROR -  Failed to filter source. Caused by Failed to filter source. {org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator}
org.wso2.carbon.mediator.service.MediatorException: Failed to filter source. Caused by Failed to filter source.
    at org.wso2.carbon.mediator.transform.SmooksMediator.handleException(SmooksMediator.java:252)
    at org.wso2.carbon.mediator.transform.SmooksMediator.mediate(SmooksMediator.java:147)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:81)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:48)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator.mediate(SequenceMediator.java:149)
    at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.ProxyServiceMessageReceiver.receive(ProxyServiceMessageReceiver.java:185)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:180)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.AbstractTransportListener.handleIncomingMessage(AbstractTransportListener.java:328)
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.vfs.VFSTransportListener.processFile(VFSTransportListener.java:751)
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.vfs.VFSTransportListener.scanFileOrDirectory(VFSTransportListener.java:407)
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.vfs.VFSTransportListener.poll(VFSTransportListener.java:177)
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.vfs.VFSTransportListener.poll(VFSTransportListener.java:124)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.AbstractPollingTransportListener$1$1.run(AbstractPollingTransportListener.java:67)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool$1.run(NativeWorkerPool.java:172)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I thinks the problem is in "T3" line(if i remove this line from csv - file is parsed, but without additional "recordElementName")

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

The fields definition in your cvs reader config does not look correct.

According to the Smooks 1.5 documentation:

> Note the sytax in the 'fields' attribute. Each record definition is separated by the pipe character '|'. Each record definition is constructed as record-name[field-name,field- name]. **record-name is matched against the first field** in the incoming message and so used to select the appropriate recodr definition to be used for outputting that record. Also note how you can use an astrix character ('*') when you don't want to name the record fields. In this case (as when extra/unexpected fields are present in a record), the reader will generate the output field elements using a generated element name e.g. "field_0", "field_1" etc. See the "magazine" record in the previous example.

Notice that the record-name is supposed to match against the first field in the row.

My understanding is the cvs reader config should be something like this in your example:

```
<csv:reader fields="T11[*] | T21[*] | T3[*]" indent="true" 
    recordElementName="message" rootElementName="messages" 
    separator="&#x9;"/>
```

Notice "T21[*]" instead of "T22[*]"

Try correcting that and see if it fixes what you suspect is a T3 problem.